# error creating solr core

Tags: apache, solr, solr6

I got this error:

```
Error CREATEing SolrCore 'my': Unable to create core [my] Caused by: Input length = 1
```

I don't have any idea about this error. I am using solr 6.2.1.
I made the collection folder, added solrconfig, schema, data-config file in conf folder, it first gave me an error to add `lang/stopwords_it.txt`, and after that it showed this error. Please help. I am new to solr.

Comment: why you creating collection folder and other things manually. create collection using collection API.

Comment: actually I followed this tutorial... https://gist.github.com/maxivak/3e3ee1fca32f3949f052.. firstly I made core using command: solr create -c but my data didn't indexed. so I tried again using this tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Under Unix, you could create a new solr core with the following bash-script:
https://github.com/patrick0585/Solr-Core-Creator

./solr_core_creator.sh --core  --conf  --lib